# wlan0 interface disappeared after upgrade to ubuntu 15.10

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking

I upgraded to Ubuntu 15.10 and now the wlan0 interface is gone from `ifconfig`. Instead, it shows a weird interface called **enxbe3baf6373f3**...

```
enxbe3baf6373f3 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr be:3b:af:63:73:f3  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:51 errors:0 dropped:2 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:13520 (13.5 KB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ec:f4:bb:86:82:f5  
      inet addr:192.168.0.10  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::eef4:bbff:fe86:82f5/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:11734 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:8303 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:12803786 (12.8 MB)  TX bytes:1178445 (1.1 MB)
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:1004 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1004 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:157958 (157.9 KB)  TX bytes:157958 (157.9 KB)
```

My Wireless hardware is an Intel 7260, which is reknown for having compatibility issues... actually in the past I had an issue which I solved by installing the most recent iwlwifi firmware. Today I did the same: `modinfo iwlwifi` shows that the kernel loads the version 12. So, after backing it up, I replaced it with the version 15.

Still, wlan0 is not showing and the issue did not change a bit...

Oh, I am running the kernel 4.2.0-16-generic.

Also, `rfkill list all` results in the following

```
0: dell-rbtn: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

And, of course, both `ifup wlan0` and `ifdown wlan0` gave the following: `Ignoring unknown interface wlan0=wlan0.`

If anyone can help it would be much appreciated.

Please let me know if I can make this question more complete by adding the output of any command...

---

**iwconfig** output:

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.
lo        no wireless extensions.
```

**iwlwifi** output:

```
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-16-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-12.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-12.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-IWL3159.8_UCODE_API_OK.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-12.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000-12.ucode
srcversion:     75056.9B888CB98F986AD49.7C2.9
alias:          pci:v00008086d000023.8F2.9sv*sd00000950bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000023.8F2.9sv*sd00000850bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000023.8F2.9sv*sd00000910bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000023.8F2.9sv*sd00000810bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000023.8F5.9sv*sd00000030bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000023.8F4.9sv*sd00000010bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000023.8F2.9sv*sd00000004bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000023.8F2.9sv*sd00009050bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000023.8F2.9sv*sd00008050bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000023.8F3.9sv*sd00009030bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000023.8F3.9sv*sd00008030bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000023.8F2.9sv*sd00009010bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000023.8F2.9sv*sd00008010bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000023.8F2.9sv*sd0000D050bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000023.8F2.9sv*sd0000C050bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000023.8F2.9sv*sd0000D010bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000023.8F2.9sv*sd0000C110bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000023.8F2.9sv*sd0000C010bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000023.8F3.9sv*sd00001030bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000023.8F3.9sv*sd00001130bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000023.8F3.9sv*sd00000030bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000023.8F2.9sv*sd00000150bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000023.8F2.9sv*sd00001050bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000023.8F2.9sv*sd00000250bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000023.8F2.9sv*sd00000050bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000023.8F2.9sv*sd00001110bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000023.8F2.9sv*sd00000110bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000023.8F2.9sv*sd00001010bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000023.8F2.9sv*sd00000010bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000094.7Asv*sd00005490bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000094.7Bsv*sd00005290bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000094.7Asv*sd00005590bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000094.7Asv*sd00005190bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000094.7Asv*sd00005090bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000094.7Asv*sd00005420bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000094.7Asv*sd0000502Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000094.7Asv*sd00005020bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000094.7Asv*sd00009410bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000094.7Asv*sd00009310bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000094.7Asv*sd00009510bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000094.7Bsv*sd00009200bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000094.7Asv*sd00009210bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000094.7Asv*sd00009112bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000094.7Asv*sd00009110bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000094.7Asv*sd0000900Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000094.7Asv*sd00009012bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000094.7Asv*sd00009010bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000094.7Bsv*sd00005202bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000094.7Asv*sd00005102bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000094.7Asv*sd00005002bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000094.7Bsv*sd00005200bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000094.7Asv*sd0000500Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000094.7Asv*sd00005000bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000094.7Asv*sd00001010bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000094.7Asv*sd00005400bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000094.7Asv*sd00005510bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000094.7Asv*sd00005410bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000094.7Asv*sd00005412bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000094.7Asv*sd00005012bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000094.7Bsv*sd00005210bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000094.7Bsv*sd00005302bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000094.7Bsv*sd00005310bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000094.7Asv*sd00005100bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000094.7Asv*sd00005110bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000094.7Asv*sd00005010bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00003164.7sv*sd00008110bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00003164.7sv*sd00008010bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00003165.7sv*sd00004210bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00003165.7sv*sd00004310bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00003164.7sv*sd00004110bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00003164.7sv*sd00004510bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00003164.7sv*sd00004410bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00003165.7sv*sd00004212bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00003164.7sv*sd00004012bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00003164.7sv*sd00004010bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000007.8B2.9sv*sd00001170bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000007.8B2.9sv*sd00001070bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000007.8B2.9sv*sd00008570bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000007.8B2.9sv*sd00008470bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000007.8B3.9sv*sd00008272bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B4sv*sd00008370bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B4sv*sd00008270bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00008062bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00008060bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00008172bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00008170bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00008072bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00008070bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B4sv*sd00000370bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000472bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000470bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B4sv*sd00000272bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B4sv*sd00000270bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000062bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000060bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000172bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000170bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000072bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000070bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C420bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000C220bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C02Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C020bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C360bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000C370bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C560bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C570bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C462bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C460bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C472bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C470bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000C262bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000C26Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000C260bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000C272bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000CC60bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000CC70bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000C270bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C760bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C770bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C162bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C062bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C160bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C06Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C060bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C170bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C072bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C070bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004420bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd00004220bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000402Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004020bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00005770bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00005170bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00005072bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00005070bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd00004360bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd00004370bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004560bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004570bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004A6Cbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004A6Ebc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004A70bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000486Ebc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004870bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004462bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000446Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004460bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004472bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004470bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd00004262bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000426Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd00004260bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd00004272bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd00004270bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004162bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004062bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004160bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000406Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004060bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004C70bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004C60bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004170bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004072bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004070bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000892sv*sd00000462bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000893sv*sd00000262bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000892sv*sd00000062bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000894sv*sd00000822bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000894sv*sd00000422bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000895sv*sd00000222bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000894sv*sd00000022bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Fsv*sd00005260bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Esv*sd00004860bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Esv*sd0000446Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Esv*sd00004460bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Fsv*sd0000426Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Fsv*sd00004260bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Esv*sd0000406Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Esv*sd00004060bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000887sv*sd00004462bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000888sv*sd00004262bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000887sv*sd00004062bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000890sv*sd00004822bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000890sv*sd00004422bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000891sv*sd00004222bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000890sv*sd00004022bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000896sv*sd00005027bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000896sv*sd00005025bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000897sv*sd00005017bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000897sv*sd00005015bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000896sv*sd00005007bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000896sv*sd00005005bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008AEsv*sd00001027bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008AEsv*sd00001025bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008AFsv*sd00001017bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008AFsv*sd00001015bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008AEsv*sd00001007bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008AEsv*sd00001005bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000084sv*sd00001316bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000084sv*sd00001216bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001326bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001226bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001306bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001206bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000084sv*sd00001315bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000084sv*sd00001215bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001325bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001225bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001305bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001205bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000886sv*sd00001317bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000886sv*sd00001315bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000885sv*sd00001327bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000885sv*sd00001325bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000885sv*sd00001307bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000885sv*sd00001305bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000089sv*sd00001316bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000089sv*sd00001311bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000087sv*sd00001326bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000087sv*sd00001321bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000087sv*sd00001306bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000087sv*sd00001301bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000091sv*sd00005226bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000091sv*sd00005225bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000091sv*sd00005221bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000091sv*sd00005207bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000091sv*sd00005206bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000091sv*sd00005205bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000091sv*sd00005201bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000090sv*sd00005216bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000090sv*sd00005215bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000090sv*sd00005211bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000008Bsv*sd00005317bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000008Bsv*sd00005315bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000008Asv*sd00005327bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000008Asv*sd00005325bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000008Asv*sd00005307bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000008Asv*sd00005305bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001305bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001304bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00004820bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000085sv*sd0000C228bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000085sv*sd0000C220bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd0000C020bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000085sv*sd00001316bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000085sv*sd00001318bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000085sv*sd00001311bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001328bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001326bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001321bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001308bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001307bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001306bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001301bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004239sv*sd00001316bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004239sv*sd00001311bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004238sv*sd00001118bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004238sv*sd00001111bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Csv*sd00001326bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Csv*sd00001321bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Csv*sd00001307bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Csv*sd00001306bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Csv*sd00001301bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Bsv*sd00001128bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Bsv*sd00001121bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Bsv*sd00001108bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Bsv*sd00001101bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Dsv*sd00001316bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Dsv*sd00001216bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Dsv*sd00001311bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Dsv*sd00001211bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Csv*sd00001326bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Csv*sd00001321bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Csv*sd00001221bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Csv*sd00001306bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Csv*sd00001206bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Csv*sd00001301bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Csv*sd00001201bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Bsv*sd00001011bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Asv*sd00001021bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Asv*sd00001001bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004236sv*sd00001114bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004236sv*sd00001014bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004236sv*sd00001111bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004236sv*sd00001011bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001104bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001004bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001101bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001001bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001124bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001024bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001121bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001021bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001316bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001216bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001315bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001215bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001314bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001214bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001311bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001211bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001326bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001226bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001325bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001225bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001324bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001224bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001321bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001221bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001306bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001206bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001305bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001205bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001304bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001204bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001301bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001201bc*sc*i*
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.2.0-16-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        6A:1C:9C:21:F0:4A:B8:6F:D1:D7:CE:D6:CA:11:35:40:FC:8E:35:B6
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size_8K:enable 8K amsdu size (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (default: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           d0i3_disable:disable d0i3 functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           lar_disable:disable LAR functionality (default: N) (bool)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)
```

**lspci** output

```
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:05ee]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=256]
    Memory at c0600000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at c0400000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=4 Masked-
    Capabilities: [d0] Vital Product Data
```

Also, the `iw list` command did not produce any output.

Comment: Pls post the output of `iwconfig`, `lspci -vnn | grep -A 10 -i net`, `modinfo iwlwifi`, and state whether `iw list` generates any output.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! Right now the issue is fixed (without me doing anything)... I saved the commands that you requested so that if it ever happens again I will be able to run them and post here their output :)

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Hello! Yesterday it happened again. I updated the question with the requested outputs. Everything was the same as stated in the original question, with the exception of `ifconfig`, which didn't show this weird **enxbe3baf6373f3** interface anymore...

Comment: Are you sure this is the whole output of the `lspci` command? This is very strange, because it does not show your wifi interface at all. Generally, iwconfig and so on do not display the wifi NIC if you do not have the appropriate driver, but lspci does show the wifi NIC.  Does `iw list` produce any output?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I was quite suprised too but yes, that's the whole `lspci` output... Also sorry, I forgot to mention that `iw list` did not produce any output at all...

Comment: I have a very similar problem, any chance you remember how you solved this @Qerubin ?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem with `udev`. I say this because your `lspci` output shows no wifi interface, which should happen even if you did not have the correct driver for the wifi card.

I `presume` the output of `iw list` is equally empty, which, if confirmed, means there was a problem with `udev` recognizing the card. Why this should be so, I do not.

I would start by changing the log level of udev,

```
      udevadm control --log-priority=info
```

(this may even be raised to `debug` level), and then you should find error messages in your syslog file (`/var/log/syslog`). Should you have any problem locating this output, try

```
      cd /var/log; grep -nrI udev
```

Then I would try forcing `udev` to re-run:

```
        udevadm trigger
```

and check whether `iw list` produces any output.

In any case, I suggest you chnage the logging rule to permanent, by changing, in the file `/etc/udev/udev.conf`, the line

```
       udev_log="err"
```

into

```
      udev_log="info"
```

or even debug, so that the next time the problem presents itself you will have some output to show.

Comment: Hey, yes the `iw list` command output is empty. I'll change the logging rule right away and try what you are suggesting when this happens again. Hopefully this will fix it. Thanks! :D

Comment: Hi. This happened again but running `udevadm trigger` did not change anything... Here is the `grep -nrI udev` output: http://pasted.co/a103866a